# Adding column titles between current titles in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm relatively new to coding so may be an easy answer! Basically I'm using pandas to import data and I want to add a column header between the original header titles. I've added the code with the names= section showing essentially what I would like to see. Help with how that is actually implemented would be a great help as I am very stuck.

`dfFQExp = pd.read_csv(fileFQExp, delimiter='\s+', names=["Original header1", "error1", "Original header2", "error2"....])`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what result you want. Do you want to create an additional column? Do you want to rename your columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to rename the column names, you can do it this way:

**By location:**

```
dfFQExp.rename(columns={ dfFQExp.columns[0]: 'new header1'}, inplace = True)
```

**By original name:**

```
dfFQExp.rename(columns={ 'Original header1': 'new header1'}, inplace = True)
```